# .htaccess to restrict access from all except one specific url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using a membership script to allow access to private files by a group of people. The problem is anyone who knows the link to the files can easily bypass the membership script and have direct access to the files. My goal is to prevent direct URL access through `http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/index.php` and to only accept access from `http://domain.com/folder1/file_with_link_to_index.php`. The membership script is useless unless I can prevent people typing in the url to the file locations.

I'm having a hard time even beginning to understand Apache but what I was attempting to do was to use "Deny All" and then "Allow from `http://folder1/file_with_link_to_index.php`." so that access to the files could only be access through the "file_with_link~" only. It didn't work. I was still able to paste the url to the files into the browser and access the directory.

I found similar questions on StackO but not enough experience to understand and actually take the little pieces that were similar to my problem and actually use them. It's probably something simple but I'm so frustrated with trying to figure this out that I can't see it.

Here's a quick example of what I was trying to use:

## deny all except those indicated here

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 12.345.67.890
 allow from http://domain.com/fold1/LINKING_FILE/program_index.php
</Limit>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm failing on the way the domain is supposed to be written and maybe that's why it's not working?

Comment: Linking examples and asking questions on them might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use another approach to this than by htaccess. Put the files in a directory unreachable for the public web, then use your membership php script to retrieve them.

Comment: Thanks, I came across that answer but it's not as easy as moving a few files. I'm trying to protect the index files (login pages) of 4 different programs/applications and one download folder so that no one can login to those programs/applications without first being processed by the membership file.

Comment: jTheMan, you were right. PHP was a better option to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

jTheMan was right. There was a better way of tackling this using PHP. My fix for my problem is below just in case it's useful to anyone else. The only awesome addition would be to make the code below allow direct URL access from just one IP, like my own :0)

I added the following file to the "head" or "index" or to the very top of the page that was called first in each application:

```
//Begin refuse direct URL Connections
$refering=parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if($refering['host']==$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
   echo "";
} else {
   header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.com");
    exit();
}
//End refuse direct URL Connections
```

Thank you!